# Show that for Abelian groups $G$ and $H, \bigl[K(G, n), K(H, n)\bigr] \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G, H).$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

Show that for Abelian groups $G$ and $H, \bigl[K(G,n), K(H,n))\bigr]  \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G, H).$

I was given a hint to use the following:

> [image]
>
> [image]
> [image]

**But I have many stupid questions:**

1-First, how I am going to use these all things in the proof?

2-Second, How I am going to prove the theorem given in the hint?

3-How am I going to prove the problem given?

4-Is there solutions to some of my problems here in this site?

we are using the book of "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory" by Jeffery Strom.

Comment: Injective + sujective = bijective, so you only need to show that $\phi$ is a homomorphism when you take $X=K(G,n)$, $Y=K(H,n)$. If you want hints about the problem you will need to be a lot more specific.

Comment: Watch out, that's not what $f_*$ is here, here $f_*$ denotes the induced map on $\pi_n$.

Comment: Ok, I am so sorry @Max

Comment: @Tyrone I need the solution of the main problem.

Comment: I think you'll be more likely to find a good answer if you specify which parts of Problem 17.45 gave you most trouble, and maybe included some of your attempts to solve them.

Comment: I just want an answer for the main question (the first question)@Tyrone

Comment: I answered question 1- entirely in my first comment. A bijective group homomorphism is a group isomorphism.

Comment: But I need a thorough proof for question 1 @Tyrone

Comment: Let $X=K(G,n)$, $Y=K(H,n)$. Then $X$ is an $(n-1)$-connected complex, so by Theorem 17.44 the map $\Phi:[X,Y]\rightarrow Hom(\pi_nX,\pi_nY)\cong Hom(G,H)$ is bijective. Since $(f+g)_*=f_*+g_*$ (where the sum $f+g$ is formed using the multiplication on $Y=K(H,n)$), we see that $\Phi$ is a group isomorphism. qed

Comment: @Tyrone if you do not mind, you can give me a proof for parts of problem 17.45 used in the solution and a proof for theorem 17.44.

Comment: @Tyrone if you gave me a detailed proof to some items (not all items)of the theorem used I will accept your answer and give you the bounty)

Comment: @Tyrone what do you mean by "the sum $f + g$is formed  using the multiplication on $Y$ in your last comment?

Comment: $K(H,n)$ is an H-space. See Strom $\S$ 9.2, especially Problem 9.14. Actually a stronger statement is true, namely that $K(H,n)$ is a loop space (see Corollary 17.46).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd prefer to give you a few more hints, rather than a complete solution. If you are still stuck with anything, let me know in the comments where, and I'll fill in some more details. I'll assume that $n>1$ below to avoid some techincal details (I'm not sure the statement is correct without this assumption).

$(a)$ Assume that $X$ is a based CW complex. For each $k\geq 0$ the $(k+1)$-skeleton $X_{k+1}$ is obtained from the $k$-skeleton $X_k$ by attaching $(k+1)$-cells. That is, there is a cofibration sequence of the form

$$\bigvee S^{k}\rightarrow X_{k}\rightarrow X_{k+1}\rightarrow \bigvee S^{k+1}\rightarrow \dots$$

Note that $\pi_kK(G,n)=0$ for $k\neq n$. Study the resulting Puppe sequence (Corollary 8.4) and use induction.

$(b)$ If $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected then you can assume that $X_n\simeq\bigvee S^n$ (see $\S$ 16.1).

$(c)$ The inclusion $X_n\hookrightarrow X$ is an $n$-equivalence for any complex $X$ (this is again $\S$ 16.1).

$(Aside)$ It might pay to observe a few facts at this point: i) If $X=S^n$ then $\phi$ is already an isomorphism (this is immediate from the definition of a $K(G,n)$). ii) $\pi_n(\bigvee S^n)\cong \bigoplus \pi_nS^n$. iii) Thus if $X=\bigvee S^n$, then $\phi$ is an isomorphism. iv) In particular, $\phi:[X_n,K(G,n)]\rightarrow Hom(\pi_nX_n,G)$ is bijective for any $(n-1)$-connected complex $X$.

$(e)$ The homomorphism $h$ determines a homomorphism $\pi_n(X_n)\rightarrow\pi_nX=H\xrightarrow{h} G$, where the first map is a surjection. We know from earlier that $X_n\simeq \bigvee S^n$ and that $[X_n,K(G,n)]\cong Hom(\pi_nX_nG)$.

$(f)$ We have the cofibration sequence

$$\bigvee S^n\xrightarrow\alpha\bigvee S^n\xrightarrow{i} X$$

and a map $\beta:\bigvee S^n\rightarrow K(G,n)$ will extend over $X$ if and only if the composition $\beta\alpha$ is null-homotopic. If $\beta$ represents $h i_*$, then $\phi(\beta\alpha)=(\beta\circ\alpha)_*=\beta_*\alpha_*=hi_*\alpha_*=h(i\alpha)_*=h0=0$. We know from earlier that $\phi(\beta\alpha)=0$ is equivalent to $\beta\alpha\simeq\ast$.

$(d)$ If $X$ is a CW complex then $X\times I$ is a CW complex. If $\dim X=n+1$, then $\dim(X\times I)=n+2$ and $(X\times \partial I)\cup (X_n\times I)$ is an $(n+1)$-dimensional subcomplex. Assume $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected and apply Theorem 16.27.

Comment: What is the importance of the groups being Abelian?

Comment: @Emptymind if $n\geq 2$ then the groups must be abelian for the Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces to be defined. If $n=1$ then there is an action of $\pi_1K(H,1)\cong H$ on the (based) homotopy set $[X,K(H,1)]$ and an action of $H$ on the set of homomorphisms $Hom(\pi_1X,H)$ which must be accounted for. The action is by conjugation, so is trivial if $H$ is abelian. Moreover $Hom(G,H)$ is not a group if $G,H$ are non-abelian. I believe the theory goes through the same for $n=1$ if you assume that $G,H$ are abelian (but note that $\pi_1(\bigvee S^1)\cong\ast\pi_1S^1$ is the free product of groups).

Comment: Could you tell me please, the Aside facts  $(i), (ii), (iii)$ from which pages of the book ?

Comment: $i)$ is straight from the definition. You just need to observe that $\pi_nS^n\cong\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by the class $[id_{S^n}]$. $ii)$ is covered by Theorem 17.66. See also $\S$ 19.3 (I think there are also some earlier disucssions. Note the exceptional $n=1$ case. $iii)$ $[\bigvee S^n,Y]=\bigoplus[S^n,Y]$ naturally.

Comment: Also, for the answer of letter(a), I have received an answer (that I am unable to match with your answer) that says " this is because Y is nullhomotopic above $n+1$ and higher cells and so there will be no obstructions to extend spheres into disks as the homotopy groups are trivial "  and also I wanted to say that we have not spoke at all about CW-complex proof by induction and we suddenly took this problem to solve ….So what should I know about this induction to understand this problem?@Tyrone

Comment: "Y is nullhomotopic above n+1 and higher cells..." is not a phrase that has any meaning. Rather they mean $\pi_kY=0$ if $k\geq n+1$, and this is exactly what I am asking you to realise in $a)$. Cofiber sequences are studied in $\S$ 8.1 (see Corollary 8.4 in particular). The phrase "...to extend spheres into disks..." indicates that you should make use of some sort of cellular structure (indeed, obstruction theory is usually set up for CW complexes). The 'obstruction' to extending a map $f:X_k\rightarrow Y$ is the composite $\bigvee S^k\rightarrow X\xrightarrow{f}Y$ in $\bigoplus\pi_kY$.

Comment: CW complexes are defined in $\S$ 3.2. The point a CW complex $X$ is formed by successively attaching cells as in the first pushout diagram on pg. 47. Each time you attach a set of cells you obtain a cofiber sequence.

Comment: I think in $(a)$ in the second line you mean by attaching $k+1$-cells .... am I correct? what I am saying is based on pg.355 in storm, the middle paragraph of the page.

Comment: @Secretly, yes, thanks for spotting the typo.