# Determining the homotopy colimit of the following diagram.

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, definition, homotopy-theory

Here is the question :

[image]

1-Could anyone tell me how to calculate the pushout of the second row? I know that I will use Fubini theorem.

2- if someone describes for me the general procedure of answering those types of questions I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technique I likes to calculate a homotopy colimit is to break it down as a sequence of left homotopy Kan extensions. The result 3.11 in Groth’s paper “derivators, pointed derivators, monoidal derivators” is great for this, as it gives conditions under which this essentially reduces to calculating homotopy pushouts.

Speaking of which, with respect to your Question 1, to calculate a homotopy pushout you might use its local universal property. This says that maps from a homotopy pushout $P=A\sqcup_C B$ are given by maps from $A$ and $B$ together with a homotopy between their restriction to $C$. (This is equivalent to the model categorical prescription of taking a cofibrant replacement followed by a non-homotopy colimit.)

In the case at hand, the functor “two maps from the point and a homotopy between their restrictions to $S^0$” represented by the homotopy colimit can also be described at “a map from $S^0$ together with two nullhomotopies.” Whether in the based or unbased category, this is given by $S^1$.

Thus one calculates the Kan extension of your diagram along the inclusion into the category which extends each row to a square as having top and bottom rows all $*$, while the middle row is a suspension square for $S^0$. If this is all at all comprehensible without diagrams, perhaps you can see now how to finish up?

Comment: what about if we replace $S^{0}$ with a general space $X$?

Comment: @Emptymind I’d be sure you’ve understood the $S^1$ example first, and then it should become clear.

Comment: Is it $\sum  X$? suspension $X$ and then finally$\sum^2 X$

Comment: and do you know other books that said that " calculating homotopy colimits reduces to calculating homotopy pushout " like where is this mentioned in AT or "Modern Classical homotopy theory" by Jeffery Strom

Comment: Could you please look at this question (if you have time) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519521/show-that-for-abelian-groups-g-and-h-biglkg-n-kh-n-bigr-cong-ope ?

Comment: I don’t know another reference for this technique, although that doesn’t mean one doesn’t exist. I’m not sure, in particular, exactly how Strom expects his readers to perform this calculation. You’re right about the double suspension.

Comment: @Emptymind The other problem is on a very standard result. It sounds like you need it for an assignment and haven’t really gotten started, so I’m not going to add anything to what’s said there, but you can find the whole result proved in various books if you really want.

Comment: I already has a proof for it but I am not convinced with it. if you know a book that contains the proof of the theorem used and the problem used and the main problem .... I would be very grateful for this.

Comment: so the homotopy colimit of the diagram (in case of $X$) is $\sum^2 X$ .... this is the final answer?

Comment: @Emptymind Yes, that's right. As for your other question, there is an excellent discussion of Eilenberg-Maclane spaces in Davis and Kirk's lecture notes on algebraic topology, though they probably still leave some details to the reader. Incidentally, if you already have a proof, however far from complete then your question should include your efforts. As it is, you essentially just ask people to write down a long argument from scratch for you, which it should be no surprise that people aren't eager to do.