# Exercise 16.10. on pg.356 in "Modern Classical Homotopy Theory."

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cw-complexes

The question is asking to show that it suffices to prove Theorem 16.2 for a path connected space $X \in \mathcal{T_*}.$

Here is Theorem 16.2:

> [image]

I believe that the answer of this question is similar to the answer of part(a) in the following link [Show that for Abelian groups $G$ and $H, \bigl[K(G, n), K(H, n)\bigr] \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G, H).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519521/show-that-for-abelian-groups-g-and-h-biglkg-n-kh-n-bigr-cong-ope) am I correct? if so could you please show me how? if not could you please show me the correct solution?

Comment: For the first part you should let $g$ be a restriction of a cellular approximation of $f$. For the next part what does $X_n$ mean if $n = \infty$? I haven't been able to figure out the case $n < m$ yet though.

Comment: You do not give much context. Neither you tell us which textbook you use nor you explain what $\mathcal T_*$ means. Many textbooks address your question. I suppose that not all details are treated sufficiently clearly in the literature, but you should invest more effort to tell us what precisely you want to know. I therefore voted to close your question.

Comment: @PaulFrost the name of the textbook is in the title.

Comment: @NoelLundström we are working from the book in the title of the question. The paragraph just before the question in the book says that When $n = \infty $ these maps between skeleta are unique up to homotopy, and it follows that any two $\infty-$skeleta are homotopy equivalent to one another..... Does this help? ..... also for your first statement, could you provide more details please?

Comment: @Secretly my "question" was a hint for you, tell me what space is $X_n$ when $n = \infty$? As for the clarification it should suffice to look up the word cellular approximation.

Comment: @NoelLundström so the solution of this question is not related to the solution in the link I mentioned .... correct?