# Proof of the existence of Moore spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

I want to solve this question, which consists of the following 2 parts:

(a) Prove that if $n \geq 1$, d is an integer, there is a map $f\colon S^n \rightarrow S^n$ of degree d.

(b) Let $G$ be a finitely-generated Abelian group. Prove that there is a CW-complex $M(G,n)$ which has $\tilde{H_{k}}(M(G,n)) = G$ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise.

**My questions are:**

1- Is there any relation between the proof of part (a) and part (b)?

2- I know how to solve the following 2 problems:

- [Show that for Abelian groups $G$ and $H, \bigl[K(G, n), K(H, n)\bigr] \cong \operatorname{Hom}(G, H).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3519521/show-that-for-abelian-groups-g-and-h-biglkg-n-kh-n-bigr-cong-ope)
- Suppose $X$ is a finite $(n-1)$-connected CW complex, and let $G$ be an abelian group. Show that the function $$D \colon \bigl[X, K(G,n))\bigr]  \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(\pi_{n}(X), G)
  $$

given by $D([f]) = f_{*}$ is bijective.

Is the solution of part (b) above similar to the solution of one of those problems? If not, could anyone show me the solution or mention a good reference that contains this proof please.

Comment: If $X$ is the mapping cone of a degree $d$ map $S^n \to S^n$, show $\tilde{H}_k(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}/d$ if $k=n$ and $0$ otherwise, i.e. $X$ is a $M(\mathbb{Z}/d, n)$. Use the fact that $\tilde{H}_*(X\vee Y)\cong \tilde{H}_*(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_*(Y)$ together with the classification theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups to construct an $M(G, n)$.

Comment: Could you explain more what is the relation between $(a)$ and $(b)$ @William ..... Sorry I did not get what you said.

Comment: (a) assures that there *is* a degree $d$ map $S^n \to S^n$ for any $d$ and any $n > 1$, and what I am saying is that such a map lets you construct a $M(\mathbb{Z}/d, n)$ for any $n > 0$ and $d > 1$, and so since $S^n$ is a $M(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ part $(b)$ is solved for all cyclic groups. Now it remains to finish the proof of $(b)$ for an arbitrary finitely-generated group $G$, which by the classification theorem decomposes as a sum of cyclic groups.

Comment: It seems like your idea for the solution of this problem is lucid, solid and intact. Could you  please share the detailed solution with us (if you do not mind)? ..... because for example I do not understand why such a map let me construct $M(\mathbb{Z}_{d}, n)$? and why that is true for any $n > 0$ and $d >1$ and why we need to have a mapping cone? @William

Comment: I've told you what the big steps are, but you should still try to complete the rest of the details for yourself as an exercise. Try solving the following sub-problems: (i) If $f\colon S^n \to S^n$ has degree $d > 1$, show that the mapping cone $C_f$ is an $M(\mathbb{Z}/d, n)$ (hint: use cellular homology. There might be other models, but this works.) (ii) Show that $M(G, n) \vee M(H, n)$ is a $M(G\oplus H, n)$. (iii) Put everything together (using the classification of finitely generated abelian groups) to prove (b). If you try and you're still having trouble, I could write up an answer.

Comment: Okay thank you very much @William

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave some hints in the comments, I thought it would be a good idea to put them in an answer and add details later if needed.

---

**Is there any relation between the proof of part (a) and part (b)?**

If $f\colon S^n \to S^n$ is a degree $d$ map and we construct the mapping cone $C_f = D^{n+1}\cup_f S^n$, then if $d\neq 0$ this will be a $M(\mathbb{Z}/d, n)$. (You can see this for example by computing the cellular chain complex of $C_f$.) By part (a) there exists such a degree $d$ map for all $n>0$, so this solves part (b) for the class of finite cyclic groups. Note that $S^n$ is a $M(\mathbb{Z}, n)$, so in fact we can prove (b) for all cyclic groups.

---

**Is the solution of part (b) above similar to the solution of one of those problems?**

Not really.

Homotopy and Homology tend to have quite different flavours, for example $\pi_n(X\times Y)\cong \pi_n(X) \oplus \pi_n(Y)$ but for the homology groups of a product you need the Künneth theorem, and the homotopy groups of a wedge can be very difficult to compute but $\tilde{H}_n(X\vee Y) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X) \oplus \tilde{H}_n(Y)$. In particular, it follows that $K(G, n) \times K(H, n)$ is a $K(G\oplus H, n)$ whereas $$M(G, n) \vee M(H, n)\text{  is a model for }M(G\oplus H, n).$$

Now to finish (b), invoke the classification theorem for finitely-generated abelian groups.